# Obtain RGB values of color given to an object

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a project in which I have to take the colors from internet websites, logo, etc.

Is there any way I can obtain the RGB value of the color where I am pointing? Or is there any way I can get the RGB values of a colored object inside it as a text, so I can give the same to other objects as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call WinAPI functions to do this.

Here's one example:
http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_graphics/article.php/c2357/A-method-to-get-the-pixel-color-under-the-mouse-pointer.htm

I've simplified it/adapted it. It'll set the color of the currently selected shape to the color of the pixel under the cursor:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
'
Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
        (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) _
        As Long

Sub Test()
    Dim tPOS As POINTAPI
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim lDC As Long

    lDC = GetWindowDC(0)
    Call GetCursorPos(tPOS)
    lColor = GetPixel(lDC, tPOS.x, tPOS.y)

    sTmp = Right$("000000" & Hex(lColor), 6)

    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lColor

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get RGB values too in that filled object or any other macro code to obtain RGB values of the selected object in it

Comment: If the selected shape is solid-filled, then ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange(1).Fill.Forecolor.RGB will give you the RGB value of the fill.  If the shape has a picture/pattern/gradient or other fill, then you'd have to resort to something like the above.